# How to form a search predicate with one to many model

Tags: one-to-many, predicate, swift-data

I have a Company and a Certificate model. Each Company can have many Certificates. There is a one to many relationship.

I cannot figure out how to form a predicate that will fetch all the certificates of a set of Companies.

Here is a bare bones view:

```
class Company {
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Certificate.company)
  var certs: [Certificate]?
}

class Certificate {
  var company: Company
}

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct MyView: View {

  @Query var certs: [Certificate]

  init(appContext: AppContext) {
    let companies = multiSel // multiSel is a Set<Company>
    
    let predicate = #Predicate<Certificate> {
      companies.contains($0.company)
    }
    _certs = Query(filter: predicate, animation: .snappy)
  }
  
}
```

The code above results the following error:

*Static method 'build_contains' requires that 'Company' conform to 'Collection'*

Comment: I don’t think this is possible but for starters you need to use `contains(where:)` instead of `contains()` to get rid of the error

Comment: Also note that you can do this without a predicate, since you have a collection of Company objects in memory you can easily use the `certs` property on each of them to get all Certificate objects.

Comment: Since I am learning, is it necessary to have the certs property defined? I am asking because for some reason the certs property does not contain all the Certificates

Comment: It’s best to have it defined in my experience.

Comment: I looked into my code and I found that, when I create a new Certificate, I don't append this certificate to the certs property. I am wondering though, if the SwiftData framework, updates this property automatically when the application starts. So far I run the database in memory only. FYI: The application runs fine without the certs property defined